# Windows Logo Kit v1.6 - Test Driver for Win7

Tags: windows, driver, windows-kernel

I've been assigned to download and install the Windows Logo Kit v1.6 to test a driver for Windows 7. What I have done so far is installed the controller and the studio on a clean Windows 2008 R2 64 bit machine. I also have another clean Windows 7 Pro 32 bit as a client. After the installation, the client machine shows in the Studio.

The next step is to install the driver on the client PC. I've tried googling around to find documentation for this part, but I haven't found any.

1. How do i install the driver on the client PC? Do i just install it the way I always do or is there a special procedures that I need to follow?
2. At the studio, there so so many tests to run. How do I know which test to select?

Comment: The documentation in the kit is actually quite comprehensive. IIRC you don't install the driver manually on the clients. You'll need a `.cat` file and an `.inf` file along with the driver, IIRC. Also, the driver has to be available in its x64 and x86 incarnations (since you want a logo) and the `.inf` must refer to the files (there is a test tool for INF file, too, in the WDK). Which tests to run depends on the driver class. Otherwise the question is quite broad.

Comment: I just verified that the driver comes with a 32 and 64 bit versions. it has both .cat and .inf file, including the exe to install.

now my question is, do i run the exe for it to install or do i leave the files in the folder? I think i have to install it for the windows to recognize it. but, i don't want to do it and screw it up right now. i need to confirm first.

anyone else has experience? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand what the problem appears to be, especially since `DTM.chm` is pretty clear on what to do and how and when. The basic steps if you have set up the DTM controller and clients and registered the clients in a "machine pool" are to open the DTM Studio on the DTM controller and then (quoting [the online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566924.aspx)):

1. Open Driver Test Manager (DTM) Studio.
2. On the **Explorers** menu, click **Device Console**.
3. Select **View By Submission**.
4. From the **Submission** control, click **New Submission**. The **Create New Submission Wizard** appears.
5. From the **Select OS** dialog box, click the Windows operating system that is installed on the client, and then click **Next**.
6. From the **Select Category** window, click ...

... and this is were it depends on your driver class etc. So without a refined question no refined answer.

Anyway, skipping a few steps ahead:

- Type the path to the INF file and click Load. You can also use the **Browse** button to find your INF file.

... this is where you are selecting your - hopefully correct and tested - INF file and the rest again depends on what you want to achieve.

If you have an MSDN subscription you also have a number of support incidents "free of charge" per year, which may be a good idea if you get stuck here. However, so far the documentation was reasonable enough to see us through ...

**Note again:** the whole process depends on your driver class.

**Also note:** there is a list of ***errata*** (Microsoft's terminology). Make sure those are up-to-date and not expired, because if you have a driver class with special needs, some tests will likely fail and you need to select the *errata* that apply to your driver then to achieve the 100% result required to get it cross-signed. We don't do the full Windows Logo process, though, but the DTM part should be the same anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is the part that I need. However, it says that to copy the .INF and/or the Driver Package to the DTM Controller.

My question is, do I install the driver on the client PC too?

Comment: @Hoan: at the risk of repeating myself: no. You don't install it explicitly yourself. This is why you roll out the DTM client packages and configure the clients with a user account etc. It is all automated. Just register it and you should be set to go.

Comment: Awesome help. Thanks 0xC0000022L (whatever that means). I will try it today.

Comment: I forgot to come back to update this. 0xC0000022L, thank you again. We were able to submit to Microsoft for logo.